# Can data contract classes inherit from one another?

Tags: wcf

I want to use data contract class as base class of some other classes. 
I know that if i want to define inherit  between two classes i need to use 'KnownType' attribute.

But in case i want to make the inherit  between more then two classes .. lets say i have also class C that inherit  from class A - how i can do it ?

I try to add '    [KnownType(typeof(C))] ' to class A definition - buts it is not working.

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(B))]
public class A
{
   [DataMember]
   public string Value { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class B : A
{
   [DataMember]
   public string OtherValue { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class C : A
{
   [DataMember]
   public string OtherValue { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have thought you'd want ;

```
[KnownType(typeof(A))]
public class B : A
{
...
}
```

as B "is a" A (for all intents and purposes of WCF serialisation). However, as you've currently got it, you are saying that A "is a" B, which isn't always the case (ie, typeof C) but on further investigation....I'd be wrong.

I've come across the Person : Contact example a few times, and I just thought I'd search for that to make sure my understanding was right, and [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598929.aspx) shows the syntax the same way you have it (anotations on the base class). It shows stacking in the following way;

```
   1. [DataContract]
   2. [KnownType(typeof(Customer))]
   3. [KnownType(typeof(Person))]
   4. class Contact {...}
   5.  
   6. [DataContract]
   7. class Person : Contact {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(B))]
[KnownType(typeof(C))]
public class A
{
 ...
}

 ...
```